# Why have some hyperlinks started being underlined and others not?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

Just noticed that some hyperlinks on pages now have hyperlinks on them. Is this some kind of test or a bug?

For example, on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59668620), under the question things like the OP's name, and the `edit` link aren't underlined:

> [image]

Under the answers, however, my and the other user's username are, as are the `share`, `edit`, etc links:

> [image]

Comments don't appear to be affected.

Just seems a bit odd. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: The change is the addition of the selector `.answercell a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag),` to the CSS rule in primary.css which used to be `.post-text a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag), .comment-copy a, .wmd-preview a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag) { text-decoration:underline }`

Comment: @Makyen You should write up an answer and write a userscript.

Comment: MSE version: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341868/underline-overflow-in-links-under-answers

Comment: Developer confirmed [this is not intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341868/underline-overflow-in-links-under-answers#comment1143839_341868).

Comment: @JL2210 I would have, but I considered the issue was most likely a CSS bug. SE tends to fix those fairly quickly. The display issue didn't frustrate me enough to put the effort into adding a fix to my personal CSS changes. OTOH, if SE had stated it was intentional and was going to remain, then I definitely would have. :-)